# two tanks control problem

Tags: control, tank

I have been trying to solve this problem for months now. I work as an Electrical Engineer in a tunnel project, we will use TBM machine to drill the underground station.

We have two tanks in TBM for grout purpose, which is Tank A and Tank B. Recently, we just realized that we actually have 2 tanks for component A (because we bought new machine from supplier, compared to the old machine that we used from previous project), making it altogether 3 tanks for grout.

The control system that we have in grout plant is to fill in the tanks if they got empty. Right now, the existing control only for one tank of comp A and comp B tank. The focus of the problem here is for comp A because it has two tanks now.

The tanks got level sensors each, for which the level sensor will send signal to PLC, and it will determine whether the valve for each tank should be opened or close. When the tank achieve both level sensor LOW and valve OPEN (I implement the AND logic here), the pump will run.

We do not intend to modify any coding in PLC since it was done by a subcontractor. What we can do is only mechanical modifications, where my boss gave an idea to use a simple relay. He asked me to crack down on how to implement it, maybe using 4 poles relay, but until now I still can't figure it out.

I was trying to implement the simple basic start and stop pushbutton circuit, where I try to manipulate the start and stop pushbutton by changing it to high and low signal from the level sensor, but the problem on how to connect them to PLC still cannot be solved, since we need to integrate two signals from two level sensors into one slot of PLC, and from one slot of output PLC to command either two valves to open.

How can I actually modify the control circuit of these two tanks?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTgnI.png)
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have a question rather than a tale of woe?

Comment: The question is how to modify the control circuit and is my approach correct?

Comment: I think you need to precisely state what you are trying to achieve i.e. if tank A is low then switch to tank B in such a way that the PLC doesn't know that this has happened (my interpretation based on your words). You haven't been particularly clear about this.

Comment: Tank B is backup for tank A. But the focus here is for the pump to fill in grout for both tank. Say Tank A is empty, level sensor will signalling LOW to PLC and this makes valve of tank A open. Thus, pump will run to fill in tank A. But the only control now only exist for tank A, we havent have any control for Tank B yet.

Comment: Edit your question with this detail. Nobody will read thru all the comments to try and figure out what you want. Also a diagram would help a lot. Be under no illusion - this problem is still under-specified despite your comment.

Comment: Why don’t you consider just connecting tank A1 with tank A2 with large pipes and use the control system « as is » , this also merts your requirement of « only mechanical modifications »...

Comment: Yes we actually did think of that idea. But then, what happens if we want to clean one tank and let the other do the works? And also, we want the system to be fully automatic, so any manual switch is not really preferred here.

Answer (score 1):

> So, in order to provide additional control for the second tank to the existing control for the first tank, I am planning to modify a little bit of the control circuit where, from the level sensor in the tank, it will send signal to the PLC in the panel. This PLC will send command for the valve to open, and hence will make the pump runs.

The panel and PLC won't have any of the controls or switchgear to read or operate sensors, valves and pumps on the second tank.
One thing you can do is add a manual multipole selection switch to choose the active tank.

The best thing is to hire the subcontractor to add features to the PLC for the second tank.

You can obviously hack a small control system that merges the two tanks into one tank. But you'll only be punishing the next engineers with unnecesary complexity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes that is exactly what I am planning to do. I'm trying to use relay as a logic circuit for the two tanks, and it should be automatically controlled. But I still don't get the exact way on how to implement it in the actual circuit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve the dual tank controls without any modification to the PLC then you have to design a small subsystem that logically merges the two tanks to appear as one tank to the existing PLC. A simple relay solution will not provide the merged solution. At best the simple relay will only allow for (1) Operation with Tank A ... **OR** ... (2) Operation with Tank B.

To support operation with Tank A ... **AND** ... Tank B you will first have to chart out just what this merged operation will work like.  Since you are the one familiar with the single tank operation *(and you have provided limited details regarding this in your question)* that definition for two tanks will be something you have to devise.

One idea could be that you devise a concept that you operate with Tank A while Tank B fills so that the existing PLC thinks that the tanks never get empty. Whether this is realistic or not is completely up to question but the concept that you should come up with is: "How can operation of this machine be made faster or more efficient using two tanks instead of just one?"

Once you have a charted out concept defined only then are you ready to move on to the implementation phase. It may very well be necessary to add a small PLC controller of your own as a subsystem to implement the state flows needed to realize the concept that has been charted out.

I suspect that the problem with the thinking and delays with the "relay idea" is that you have jumped right into the implementation space without stepping back and making a concept for what a dual tank system means and how it can be made better than a one tank system.